# generated XSD From Java use moxy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

```
@XmlRootElement
public class OtherClass {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String other;
}
@XmlRootElement
public class Simple extends OtherClass {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    @XmlValue
    public String contents;
}

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(OtherClass.class,Simple.class);
System.out.println(context);
System.out.println("org.eclipse.persistence.Version:"+Version.getVersionString());
context.generateSchema(new MySchemaOutputResolver());
System.out.println(sw);
```

Use woxy generated XSD results

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@1292d26
org.eclipse.persistence.Version:2.5.0.v20130425-368d603
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="otherClass">
      <xsd:sequence/>
      <xsd:attribute name="other" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="simple">
      <xsd:simpleContent>
         <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/> 
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="otherClass" type="otherClass"/>
   <xsd:element name="simple" type="simple"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

sample/other no inheritance in xsd, but there is in java

Excuse me, if to solve the problem? Here I thank you first

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

### What the Mappings Mean

With MOXy as your JAXB provider (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) you can use the folllowing code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Simple.class, OtherClass.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18029865/input.xml");
        Simple simple = (Simple) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(simple, System.out);
    }

}
```

to convert the following XML to/from your Java objects:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<simple id="foo" other="bar">Hello World</simple>
```

---

### How the Mappings Relate to XML Schema

The classes as you have mapped them don't have a real representation in XML schema.  Since you have used the `@XmlValue` annotation the resulting type will extend `xsd:string`, but you have also indicated that it should extend the complex type corresponding to `OtherClass`.

---

### What the JAXB Reference Implemenetation Does

For the exact same mappings the JAXB RI will through an exception when creating the `JAXBContext`.  Since this representation is not allowed in the XML schema, they decide not to allow it in the mappings. I prefer the option we chose in MOXy where still support the mapping.

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String forum18029865.Simple.contents
        at forum18029865.Simple

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at forum18029865.Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

Comment: My basic model determines the **xmlvalue** must be used in many classes, and most of them are **subclasses**
So if the generated XSD right?